# How to load a JavaScript file with React Router 4?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-v4

I have external JavaScript files in index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
 ...blah blah
  <div id='app'></div>
  <script src='bundle.js'></script>
  <script src="./assets/js/autocomplete.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

When the page loads first time everything works fine but when I navigate using React Router 4 menu links then autocomplete.js won't load unless I reload the page.

How can I reload autocomplete.js using RR? Or some other way.

I believe onEnter is deprecated otherwise it would be

`<Route onEnter={load autocomplete.js ??}/>`

So render needs to be used instead

App.js

```
export default class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <Header />
        <Route exact path='/' component={ Home }/>
        <Route path="/login" component={ Login }/>
        <Route path="/register" component={ Register }/>
        <Route path="/edit-profile" component={ EditProfile } />
        <Footer />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Header.js

```
const Header = ()=>(
    <nav className="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-inverse fixed-top bg-inverse">
    <button className="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" 
      data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" 
      aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <Link to="/" className="navbar-brand">Bar</Link>
        <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
            <ul className="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li className="nav-item active">
                    <Link className="nav-link" to="/login">Login</Link>
                </li>
        <li className="nav-item">
                    <Link className="nav-link" to="/register">Register</Link>
                </li>
                <li className="nav-item">
                    <Link to="/edit-profile" className="nav-link">Edit Profile</Link>
                </li>        
            </ul>

            <form className="form-inline mt-2 mt-md-0">
                <input className="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text"/>
                <button className="btn btn-search my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
            </form>

        </div>
    </nav>
);
```

index.js

```
import App from './components/App';

ReactDOM.render(
<BrowserRouter>
  <Provider store={ store }>
    <App/>
    </Provider>
</BrowserRouter>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Edit. The solution I went with:

inside componentDidMount:

```
const script = document.createElement("script");

script.src = "/assets/js/autocomplete.js";

document.body.appendChild(script);
```

Comment: Can you share your react-router code

Comment: Where do you need your autocomplete.js, I guess on the Header.js ? You need to use the autocomplete in a programmatically way I think. Inside the Header component, on componentDidMount you trigger the autocomplete.

Comment: @ChrisR Thanks, it works beautifully. If you post it as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: Hi, I am also facing same issue. How did you solved it? I did not understand from the answer. Please help me

Comment: @SaurabhSharma I edited my question to include the solution I went with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(*Taken from my comment above ^*)

Inside the Header component, on `componentDidMount` you trigger the autocomplete instead of letting it execute itself on script load.